# How to goBack to startpoint in a WKWebView History

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to find a way to jump backwards to the startpoint in a `WKWebView` History.

Let's say i have a Main/Start-Page (`WKWebView init`) with a Link to google.com.

So i'm clicking at the Link and next at **google.com** i click another link **maps.google.com**. So i'm 2 steps away from my start-page.

How can i jump back directly to the Main/Startpage without reload or reinit the `WKWebView` ?

I have tried the following implementation but with no success:

```
-(void)backNavigationToStart{
    if([vuMain canGoBack]){
        WKBackForwardList *list = [vuMain backForwardList];
        if(list && list.backList){
            WKBackForwardListItem *item = [list itemAtIndex:0];
            [vuMain goToBackForwardListItem:item];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the meaning of the index argument to -itemAtIndex:

“Index of the desired list item relative to the current item: 0 for the current item, -1 for the immediately preceding item, 1 for the immediately following item, and so on.” https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKBackForwardList_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKBackForwardList/itemAtIndex:

Use an appropriate negative index, or use the first item in backList.

Answer (score 6):

Pure swift solution:

```
    // find first item in history
    let historySize = webView.backForwardList.backList.count
    let firstItem = webView.backForwardList.item(at: -historySize)

    // go to it!
    webView.go(to: firstItem!)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to navigate to the first item in the browser's history.

```
extension WKWebView {
    func goBackToFirstItemInHistory() {
        let script = "window.history.go(-(window.history.length - 1));"
        evaluateJavaScript(script) { (_, error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the first item in the backList, if available (if you have navigated forward, i.e.) - this will be your home page.

```
@objc func goHome() {
    if (webView.backForwardList.backList.count > 0) {
        webView.go(to: webView.backForwardList.backList[0])
    }
}
```